# Sharing Git Patches between IntelliJ Idea & Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea, egit

Our team  uses both IntelliJ Idea (v11 and v12) and Eclipse, maintaining a project that is stored in Git.

We're looking to exchange patches between users, in order to do pre-commit reviews.

It appears that patches created by Idea are always relative to the .idea project directory, whereas patches created by Eclipse EGit plugin are created relative to the root of the repository.

Is there a way to either

- Configure IntelliJ Idea/Eclipse to specify the base directory of the patch?
- Modify the generated patch files to specify the base directory of the patch?

Comment: Why don't you push/pull between each user instead?

Comment: @maba we're looking at using Crucible for code reviews, which uses patch files for pre-commit reviews. Also, would require visibility of developers repos - not necessarily simple...

Comment: Ok, I see. So are you saying that the git repo root and the IntelliJ project root are not the same? In that case you can change the `VCS Directory Mapping` to  point to the directory instead of the project.

Comment: My project is already configured that way - the project root is in an immediate subirectory of the repo, e.g. `D:\the-repo\.idea`; `D:\the-repo\` is mapped in the `VCS Directory Mapping` of the project to Git.

Comment: Actually - my IDEA Project directory was  two  levels deeper than the root of the depot, not one; this appears to work, although it's less than ideal IMHO.

Comment: Agree, this kills us as well.